# What's the max length for a quote?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

What's the max length for a quote?

I am asking as [this answer quoting 5 sentences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/22894/43) got removed because "A link with a lengthy copy/paste isn't an acceptable answer."

Copy of the answer: [see the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200402173856/https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/whats-the-max-length-for-a-quote).

Answer (score 3):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

It's not just length. YOU have to provide an answer. The answer you provided was really just a "google this for me" answer.

Comment: "Quote only the relevant portion" -> that is what I did.

Comment: "YOU have to provide an answer." -> the quote is the answer.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, it could do with a summary in your own words, perhaps something along the lines of "tests involving the related SARS-CoV and MERS-CoV viruses show promise".

Comment: @Mark Thanks, added. I still think that shouldn't warrant deleting the answer as Carey Gregory did since the quote is clear and concise.

Comment: I can't put answers on hold so they can be edited and reopened. I can only leave them to stand or delete them. But they can be undeleted and I'll be perfectly happy to do that if you're willing to edit it and provide a real answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory It was a real answer. Anyway, why don't you delete https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/22822/43 then, which is "just a lengthy quote" and therefore not a real answer to your eyes?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt He answered his own question, which is a mechanism for providing information. And you even made a trivial edit to it right before posting this comment. But if you're going to be this petulant then flag it and I'll delete it.

Comment: @CareyGregory my point, which you have to totally missed, is that 1) a quote can be a perfectly valid answer 2) you have no consistency whatsoever in your deletion sprees. And my edit wasn't trivial, since many readers don't know what Semo is.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt 1) Your _opinion_ conflicts with SE policy as I linked to above. 2) I don't do deletion sprees. I respond to flags from the community, and if you think this job is so easy then why don't you step up and try it yourself instead of making yourself the highest maintenance user on the site?

Comment: And now I see that you've re-posted the exact same answer, just shorter. You know, I really don't have time for this nonsense so I've undeleted your answer as you wish and left the other answer you complained about to stand. You get your way, Frank.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do ... "Remember, you still have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text, even when attributed, is not your work either. Use quotes sparingly, to support your own words." - What you are doing here with copy paste answers is **totally unacceptable and damages the StackExchange platform**. I think you owe Carey an apology for how you've treated him here.

Comment: @BryanKrause What's the point in using my own words when the **quote is self-explanatory**? For example https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/22822/43 was **well received, despite just being a quote**. Why don't you let the votes speak instead of flagging such answer for deletion?

Comment: @Franck It is a form of plagiarism and violates copyright principles. A lot of people are voting right now on covid19 questions who are not typical users of the site. You need to write things in your own words and use quotes as support.

Comment: I also don't like the question you linked to and I flagged that one as well.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yes, you've long made it clear that you view standards agreed upon by the community as irrelevant when they inconvenience you.  And when those standards get applied to you, I know we can count on a new meta thread complaining about the unfair treatment you've received. And please stop pointing to Graham Chiu's post as proof of your mistreatment. A self-answered question intended to simply publicize information is an entirely different matter.

Comment: @CareyGregory Graham Chiu's post is an example of useful, quote-only answer. The fact that is is a self-answered question changes nothing.

Comment: @BryanKrause A small quote (e.g., a few sentences) is fair use and not plagiarism, as long as it is clearly identified as a quote and with proper reference.

Comment: @Franck Not if you don't provide any other useful content. Your answers are entirely quotes and a link. You have contributed no original content in those answers.

Comment: @BryanKrause 1) That doesn't make it plagiarism. We are both researchers: this makes you accusing me of plagiarism even more outrageous. You can't throw such an accusation that lightly in the research world. 2) My contribution is finding the reference. Once again, we are both researchers so you should know that finding a proper reference is useful in itself.

Comment: @Franck You are wrong, but I don't know how else to convince you. I've provided supporting references to StackExchange policy. It seems nothing will convince you. I'm emphasizing this exactly because I do not take this lightly. Finding a reference is not sufficient contribution. It's not difficult to write these things in your own words and use references for support.

Comment: @BryanKrause "You are wrong" -> Are you saying that I plagiarized some text?  "Writing these things in [my] own words and use references for support" is indeed easy but useless if the quote is clear. What's the point in rephrasing a clear quote?

Comment: Again, read the answer I linked: "Remember, you still have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text, even when attributed, is not your work either. Use quotes sparingly, to support your own words." An answer that is only a link and a quote is not acceptable.

Comment: I try not to make moderation decisions out of irritation but, this is coming to an end now. I'm going to enforce SE's policy by removing both @FranckDernoncourt's and Graham's lengthy quote-only posts as copyright violations.

Comment: @CareyGregory so what's the max length for a quote  not be a copyright violation?

Comment: Depends on the answer of course. For quote-only answers, a single sentence is too long because you can't claim fair use if you provided no original content. That's just out and out plagiarism. For well-reasoned answers, as long as is needed to support the points being made, but no longer.

Comment: @CareyGregory I provided some "original content" in a later edit the answer. Why did you delete it after I had provided some "original content"?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Deleted what? I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @CareyGregory you deleted the answer https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/22894/43

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yes, your answer and Graham's answer that you complained about were both deleted. We've been through this endlessly. Time to let it go.

Comment: @CareyGregory I had added my own words in addition to the quote. Therefore the answer isn't link+quote only anymore, and as a result shouldn't be deleted according to your criteria.

Comment: And now that you brought it to my attention, I've also deleted this answer for the same reason. You wanted consistency, and you're right. I should be consistent. So answers lacking original content will be deleted. https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/22900/805

Comment: @CareyGregory my answer https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/22894/43  now has some original content, isn't that enough? The content was suggested by the OP themselves.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You added a single sentence telling us the material you're quoting doesn't actually answer the question. Instead of trying to appease me with the absolute minimum possible, how about trying to understand the views of the community and cooperating with them? If you want the guidelines changed, you know how to go about that.

Comment: @CareyGregory 1) the quote does answer to the question to some extent (probably why it got upvoted) 2) did you delete the answer because you think it doesn't answer the question, or because the "original work" is insufficient? That's unclear from your previous comment

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Original work is insufficient. It's a single sentence that does nothing to answer the question. Do you really not understand the the guideline?

Comment: @CareyGregory the OP themselves thought it was sufficient, and I agree. What else do you want me to write in my "original work" summarizing the quote?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I see, so you really don't understand the guideline. I don't know how to help you. We're done here.